# Why does loop work this way?

Tags: c, string, loops, while-loop

I created a program. It works as I wanted it to work, but I don't understand why.

This is the function.

```
void LiteraMajuscula(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (i == 0 && str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
            str[i] -= 32;
        if (str[i-1] == ' ' && str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
            str[i] -= 32;
        i++;
    }
}
```

It is supposed to make the lowercase character into an uppercase one each time there is a space and only the first one and if the first character from a string is lowercase, make it an uppercase.

The only thing i dont understand is the `str[i-1]`. I tried `str[i]`, but it doesn't change anything, and `str[i-2]` changes the second letter into and uppercase instead of the first one. Why is that?

Comment: `str[i-1]` is undefined behavior (because you start with `i=0`

Comment: `str[i-1] == ' '` is UB if `i == 0`

Comment: Yes, it should have been `else if`, since the first if statement addresses the case of i=0.

Comment: The correct approach for answering such questions is to apply [debugging techniques to your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Even if there are no bugs, the process is about understanding the insides of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the loop is incorrect

```
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if (i == 0 && str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        str[i] -= 32;
    if (str[i-1] == ' ' && str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        str[i] -= 32;
    i++;
}
```

When `i` is equal tp 0 then in this condition

```
    if (str[i-1] == ' ' && str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        ^^^^^^^^
```

there is an attempt to access memory beyond the string. The loop should be rewritten at least like

```
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if ( ( i == 0 || str[i-1] == ' ' ) && str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        str[i] -= 32;
    i++;
}
```

That is the condition checks whether the first character of the string is an alpha character or if it is not the first character of the string whether the previous character is space and the current character is an alpha character.

Take into account that the function will not work with EBCDIC characters. It is better to use standard C function `toupper` declared in header `<string.h>`. For example

```
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if ( i == 0 || str[i-1] == ' ' )
    { 
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)s[i]) ) s[i] = toupper((unsigned char)s[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

I think it is desirable also to check whether the previous character is the tab character. Also such string functions usually return the target string.

I would write the function the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * LiteraMajuscula( char *s )
{
    for (size_t i = 0; 
         s[i += strspn(s + i, " \t")] != '\0'; 
         i += strcspn( s + i, " \t" ))
    {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)s[i]) ) s[i] = toupper((unsigned char)s[i]);
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "hello,\tworld!";

    puts(s);
    puts(LiteraMajuscula(s));

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
hello,  world!
Hello,  World!
```

Comment: "Take into account that the function will not work with EBCDIC characters." How is that a bad thing?

Comment: @Lundin It depends on your qualification. Either you have enough qualification that to understand that a function should be more generic, or you have no enough qualification and for each particular case write a separate function.

Answer (score 3):

`str[i] -= 32;` will convert the character at index `i`. The reason the second `if` statement uses `str[i-1] == ' '` in its check is so it knows whether the current character (at `i`) is just after a space (at `i - 1`). The reason it converted the *second* character of words when you changed it to `str[i-2] == ' '` is that you changed it so it converted a character if it (at `i`) was **two** characters after a space (at `i-2`).

As noted in the comments, the code there has undefined behavior, because there's nothing preventing the `str[i-1] == ' '` check when `i` is `0`, so `str[i-1]` would be accessing the character **before** where `str` is pointing.

Separately, since most of the conditions and logic are duplicated between the two `if`s, this is where you'd use `||` (logical OR):

```
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if ((i == 0 || str[i-1] == ' ') && str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        str[i] -= 32;
    i++;
}
```

*(Note the `()` around the `||`.)*

`||` short-circuits, so when `i` is `0` and the first operand is true, the second operand (`str[i-1] == ' '`) is never evaluated and so you avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers posted have explained what was wrong with the code.

Here is an alternative way that the function can be rewritten to be more efficient and more portable, with the use of functions from ctype.h:

```
void do_some_incorrect_capitalization (char str[])
{
  if(*str == '\0')
  {
    return ;
  }

  *str = toupper(*str); // special case, first letter in the string
  str++;

  while(*str != '\0')
  {
    if(isspace(*(str-1)))
    {
      *str = toupper(*str);
    }
    str++;
  }    
}
```